# What is the best way to call fragments method from ViewModel in MVVM architecture using live data

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-mvvm

For eg, As ViewModel should be loosely coupled we cant pass interface reference to ViewModel to get a callback from Viewmodel and call the method implemented in the fragment.

Also please provide an example or reference to call with methods with two or more params using livedata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a live data variable in ViewModel and attach an observer in Fragment to that variable and whenever there will be a change in data then the function will be automatically invoked.

**For Example:**

```
   viewModel.loading.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { loading ->
        loading?.let {
          // Here, I'm calling a new function named setLoaderVisibility

            setLoaderVisibility(loader = binding.shimmerProductDetail, binding.containerBody, isLoaderVisible = loading)
        }
    })
```

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Agree, but what if the method in fragment have two or more params, and we need to call this parameterized fragments method from viewmodel

Comment: You need to pass the parmas in viewModel using constructor and when need to call fragment pass the parmas......